# Proving that there is a $\theta\in(13\pi/6 , 7\pi/2 )$ s.t. $\tan(2\theta - 5\pi)\tan(3\theta + 4\pi) = 2/3$

Tags: functions, continuity

> Prove that there is a $\theta\in (13\pi/6, 7\pi/2 )$ such that
>
> $$\tan(2\theta - 5\pi)\tan(3\theta + 4\pi) = 2/3.$$

I started by defining a function on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = \cos 3x\sin 2x$ hoping to end up with something but I'm really stuck as I have to prove that it is continuous on that given range etc.

Is there anyone who has a different approach than that ?

Comment: thank you so much @MPV

Comment: Why cosine and sine in your function $f$, when you have tangents in the question?

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is the following. You can use a continuity argument if you can show that there is one $\theta$ in this interval with the function taking value less than $2/3$ there, that there is another $\theta$ in the interval with the function taking value greater than $2/3$ there, and that the function is continuous on the interval

Comment: @Andrei because some functional points are not define in $tan$ such as at 90 degrees it is not defined , so to use continuity Id rather use a function on $sin$ and $cos$

Comment: But that's wrong. You cannot ignore that a function is not defined when you use continuity.

Comment: Actually sir I can , I think with the help of what MPV said I can use Rolle's theorem to find a theta for my answer

Comment: Check in that interval where are the discontinuities. Then the function is continuous on each subinterval between those points. Find the minimum and maximum values for those subintervals.

Comment: @LasanManujithaUkwaththaLiya correct on your last comment, but you can't change the function. Just find the minimum and maximum in each subinterval, and if you have one such subinterval where minimum is less than $2/3$ and maximum is greater that $2/3$ then you are done